# Run each test in a new container

Tags: docker, cmake, googletest, ctest

I have google test based test suite. Since the tests manipulate the filesystem and do other things that I don't want to be left behind in case of a test crash, besides just not playing nicely with running tests on parallel, I want to run each test case in a new container. I am currently using CTest (aka. CMake test) to run the gtest binary, but I am not very attached to either of these, so if the best option is some other tool, I can accept that.

Can anyone suggest a way to automate this? Right now I am adding each individual test case manually to CTest with a call to docker run as part of the test command, but it is brittle and time consuming. Maybe I am doing this wrong?

Comment: A thought... you could abuse the `CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR` feature, which `add_test` uses to determine a test runner and point it to a script that launches Docker. You'd need some way of determining when you're running under CTest, though, so that normal compiles can go through. Checking the `CTEST_INTERACTIVE_DEBUG_MODE` env-var might suffice.

Comment: Alternatively, you could write a script that processes the output of `ctest --show-only=json-v1` and runs CTest on each individual test in separate Docker containers.

Comment: You may want to look into using Bazel for building and running tests and use Sandboxing: https://bazel.build/docs/sandboxing

Answer (score 0):

You can run your GTest runner with `--gtest_list_tests` to list all tests.

You can then loop through this list and call your GTest runner with `--gtest_filter` set to the name of specific test.

The format of the list is a bit awkward to parse though, so need some shell scripting skills to get the actual test names.

Check the exit code of the GTest runner the know whether the test succeeded or failed.

I do not know if this integrates well with CTest.